# right click menu opens up on pressing 'a' button in keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Whenever I press the <kbd>A</kbd> button on my keyboard the right-click menu opens up. I have updated my driver to the newest version and confirmed there was no shortcut key assigned. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Any binary values under this registry key? `'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'`?

Comment: there are two things named DoshkeybCodes and DoskeybIDs

Comment: No value named **Scancode Map** in the right-hand pane?

Comment: No, Scancode Map is not looking only those two which i mentioned above and they have some kind of codes and data inside it